# document.getElementById on a different folder and file

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to trigger a modal once the registration is clicked (if all reg conditions are met). how will i able to do it in my situation?

[image: visuals]

modal_popup (js): id=register needs to be in var btn

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.getElementById("");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

register (cards): would like the register here as the variable on the first code.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn form-control color-white mwc-orange-background-color" id="register" name="register" value="REGISTER">
```

modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">


  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Welcome, New White Card Holder!</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body spacer-left spacer-right">
      <br>
      <h3>Congratulations, you are entitled for a 30-day free trial of our Elite Membership.</h3>
      <h3>Enjoy a wealth of deals for wellness!</h3>
      <h3>If you wish to avail of our other membership options, click here.</h3>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>WAT</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: on your `input[type="Submit"]` add a function to on the `onclick` attribute like `onclick=validate()` then in that function `return true;` if every condition is passed else `return false;`.

Comment: is this related to getting the id name to my modal_popup.js file?

Comment: yes, you can put your modal-popup code in the function as long as the modal's `HTML` code and the `js` code calling it are on the same view.

Comment: i dont get the "are on the same view" can you provide examples?

Comment: **are on the same view** means the web page displayed which for you is `register.php`. should have the `HTML` code for the modal and the `javascript` file/code that will trigger the `modal`

Comment: thats the exact reason i asked this question. im looking for the way for the javascript to trigger the modal once register is clicked.

Comment: i would love to see some examples because im so close at making my code work